# Getting forbid(4.3) error in deploying my war on wildfly 12

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I have a project working fine on tomcat, But after making war of same project and deploy on Wildfly 12 project get deploy but getting forbidden on browser .

Comment: Check authentication, you might not have permissions to see the content ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i was making a war file of my project from window it is add one more directory with folder name in which i am making war using (jar -cvf mywarname.war) which cause forbiden  issue due different directory structure .

but when i am running same command on linux it does not adding directory .it just copy context in war file . So it is working fine by making war from linux mahince .